# An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full - wamp server

Tags: mysql, sockets, memory, configuration, wamp

I am creating a browser-based game using PHP,Javascript and HTML5 and I am testing it on a local wamp server. However sometimes I get the following error:

```
 Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full.
```

It flashes on the screen (like a SCREAM error) and then dissapears. It doesn't affect the functionality of the application, but sometimes it can stay up to 5-10s on the screen. I mention that I am using a lot of AJAX requests to operate modifications in the database, the most notable one being the fact that i have a timer that reads the svg map set at 2s. I found the following lines in the my.ini (mysql configuration file). Should I try to modify some of these values?

```
# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
basedir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24
log-error=c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log
datadir=c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.5.24/data
```

Or perhaps I should take a look in the php.ini file? Also, I am running the wamp server on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this steps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx

Mine problem was the same, first solution listed there helped!

Comment: The article has moved here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/understanding-the-error-8220-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not/ba-p/383535